# Extract Data from a website or text document using PHP and save in database

Tags: php, mysql, extract

I am building a Geo-location app. I have a list of street names and their
co-ordinates which I found on the following website [streets](https://geographic.org/streetview/south_africa/gauteng/mamelodi.html) . This list 
consists of 4000+ street names and co-ordinates. I am trying to add the 
list onto my database. Can anyone show me how I can extract this data
from the website or from a text document and insert it into my database
table preferably using PHP.

DATABASE TABLE EXAMPLE

---

```
TABLE `street_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

TEXT DOCUMENT EXAMPLE

---

```
A Kriel Street         -25.69664263     28.41030434
Abraham Mogopodi Avenue         -25.71338241     28.37033247
Absalome Street         -25.70997386     28.3568847
Alan Paton Street         -25.72122505     28.42021664
Alfred Nzo Crescent         -25.6882444     28.41519928
Annah Mabusela Street         -25.70656941     28.34339845
Anton Lembede Street         -25.71813448     28.41874969
Aphane Nhlapo Street         -25.7208474     28.38598257
Apple Close         -25.71151327     28.38914898
Areyeng Street         -25.72404151     28.38545561
Aseletho Street         -25.71910848     28.41628606
Azikwelwa Street         -25.70616386     28.40821879
Azondo Street         -25.69615534     28.41117811
B Z Ndlazi Street         -25.71074853     28.37073878
Badanile Avenue         -25.71883255     28.42320088
Bahula Street         -25.70728106     28.35488834
Baloyi Close         -25.72553726     28.38641741
Bana Street         -25.70942133     28.40631067
Banana Close         -25.71194649     28.39090203
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: How can a street have a precise coordinate? What if it's 1000km long?

Comment: @Mike Most probably its where the street starts e.g. Stackoverflow street 1 or maybe the center of the street so if it is the point 500km from your street start point.You can find so many possibilities that make sense  and it is not related to the question anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this regex would accomplish what you want. This also assumes the data format is consistent and plain text.

```
(?m)^(?P<Street>(?:[A-Za-z\d]+\h)+)\h{2,}(?P<LAT>-?\d*\.\d+)\h{2,}(?P<LON>-?\d*\.\d+)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/ctUp0L/1/

It seems like the data points are broken up by at least 2 white spaces so I used that as a delimiter. This could also be done with `explode` and `preg_split`.

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $lines_array[] = preg_split('/\h{2,}/', $line, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/DaunT